# How do I calculate percentage of N numbers?

Tags: javascript, percentage

I have an array of objects that consists in different keys and one in particular we need,

rating: 1-5 ( This value can go to a minimum of 1 to a maximum of 5 )

I would like to calculate the percentage of all the object

Currently my code ( It only give the correct result for 2 number ):

```js
const feedbacks = [
  { rating: 1 },
  { rating: 3 },
  { rating: 4 },
  { rating: 2 },
  { rating: 5 }
];

function calculatePercentage() {
  console.log(feedbacks);
  let percentage = 0;
  feedbacks.map(feedback => {
    switch (feedback.rating) {
      case 1:
        feedback.ratingPercentage = 20;
        break;
      case 2:
        feedback.ratingPercentage = 40;
        break;
      case 3:
        feedback.ratingPercentage = 60;
        break;
      case 4:
        feedback.ratingPercentage = 80;
        break;
      case 5:
        feedback.ratingPercentage = 100;
        break;
    }
  })

  for (let i = 0; i < feedbacks.length - 1; i++) {
    percentage += feedbacks[i].ratingPercentage / feedbacks[i + 1].ratingPercentage;
  }

  percentage = percentage * 100;

}
calculatePercentage()
console.log(feedbacks)
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here.

Comment: If you have a rating from 1-5, if you want to get a percentage, just multiply by 20? `feedback.rating * 20` = percentage.

Comment: Do you mean an average of the ratings?

Comment: I made you a snippet. What is expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you actually want to calculate the average of the (percentage) ratings. You can just sum all the percentages and divide by the length of the array. It could be done in a one-liner, but I feel it's better to show the expanded version:

```
var average = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < feedbacks.length; i++) {
    average += feedbacks[i].ratingPercentage;
}
average = average / feedbacks.length;
console.log(average);
```

Comment: Thank you, the example you provided works but I have replaced in the for loop feedbacks.length - 1 to feedbacks.length otherwise it doesn't get the last number

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I copied your loop and didn't check the condition. I'll edit it.